# How can I insert an HTML into a div with php code?

Tags: php, html

I want to use a navigation bar with several hyperlinks in order to call external HTML pages but I don't want to repeat the whole webpage into the code inside the others.

So I was thinking about calling the webpages when clicking on the links with the aim to insert the external pages into a div inside my index.html.

Is this possible by using php code easily?

Or I need to use jquery?

Thanks in advance for the response.

Comment: share your code what you have tried so far?

Comment: You cannot use php tag inside .html file

Comment: According to what I can understand, you don't need php. What u need is jquery

Comment: You can use `iframe` for that

Comment: Why cant you use `<iframe src="yourpage_link"></iframe>` ??

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED
If you want to load a page in the div when the page loads in the first place you can do it like this;

```
<div id="load_content_div"><?php include "path/to/page"; ?></div>
```

But if you don't want to use php code in your page the use the jQuery method to load a content to the div at first load:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#load_content_div').load('path/to/page');
});
```

Then you use this to load a page to the div when a link is clicked:

```
<div id="load_content_div"></div>
//the hyperlinks
<a href="javascript:;" alt="page1.html">link1</a>
<a href="javascript:;" alt="page2.html">link2</a>
<a href="javascript:;" alt="page3.html">link3</a>
```

Then you use the jQuery ajax method like this:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    page = $(this).attr('alt');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: page,
        cache: false,
        success:function(data){
            $('#load_content_div').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

But remember to include you jQuery library to your code

Answer (score 0):

I think you need both php and javascript(jQuery, Ajax).

You can write you navigation as a list including hyperlinks as a html file. and yo u include it using php code.

```
<!-- nav.html -->
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Your nav li here</li>
  <li>...</li>
</ul>


<?php
  // index.php
  include 'path/to/nav.html';
  // your other code
?>
```

then you can include your other html page via javascript and ajax

Answer (score -2):

Oh dear, its soo easy with PHP.
You need to create an index.php page with this structure(and a startingContent.html, and one html for each page so you can link them):

```
<body>
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="?p=content1"> Page 1 </a></li>
        <li><a href="?p=content2"> Page 2 </a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <?php
        if(isset($_GET['p'])) { 
            $pag = $_GET['p']; 
        } 
        else { 
            $pag = "indexContent"; 
        }
        include ($pag.".html");
        ?>
</div>
```

Real men don´t use Jquery ;)

Comment: lol... PHP makes your page to reload each time the link is clicked. But jQuery just loads up the data into the required div without having the stress of reloading........ :p

Answer (score -2):

You can do it with just Jquery too:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {

        $( "#btn1" ).click(function() {

            $( "#display" ).load( "test.html" );

        });

    });
</script>
```